# Is there any undergraduate mathematics learning website like edx or coursera?

Tags: soft-question, online-resources

I want to take courses in mathematics of undergraduate level. But in edx or coursera they have only few undergrad math courses( only calculus or a little bit of algebra). There are no hardcore maths courses like group theory, ring theory etc. Is there any site where I can get these?

Thanks!

Comment: For "hardcore" things you need some books more than some "vids".

Comment: There's quite a lot of "hardcore" maths courses on Coursera if you dig deep enough into the catalogue. I assume you're out for something between "freshman level maths" and "master's level maths"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at MIT open courseware http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/

Comment: But there are no video lectures there, right?

Comment: For some courses there are, but mostly the elementary ones then, like calculus or that little bit of algebra :/

Comment: There are Linear Algebra video lectures by Gilbert Strang, no less.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any website that collects these all in one place, in the way that edX or Coursera.

But most Ivy League universities offer at least free lecture videos, sometimes the problem sets and tests too, if you look around. For instance, here's [one course on Abstract Algebra, from Harvard](http://wayback.archive-it.org/3671/20150528171650/https://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra).

Answer (score 0):

There are also MOOC courses by top Indian institutions, funded by the Government.

You can find them here:

- https://nptel.ac.in/course.html
- https://nptel.ac.in/noc/courses/111/